# Double substitution when integrating.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate
$$f(x) = \cos(\sin x)$$
my first thought was substituting so that $u = \cos(x)$, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there any way to do a double substitution on this?

Any ways on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not certain that this is integrable in elementary terms -- Wolfram Alpha doesn't think so. It's not the sort of thing that tends to show up in physics/math/chem problems, and I'm wondering where the need to integrate it arose. Regardless, you'll probably need to use numerical integration to get an approximation.

Comment: Is it a definite integral? For such, there may be ways to evaluate the integral exactly.

Comment: Yes, it is a definite integral, and I know how to integrate it that way. Just out of curiosity I wondered if there was any way to find the indefinite integral.

Comment: You may expand the integrand in a series in terms of $\sin x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the indefinite integral $($or anti-derivative$)$ [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions, its definite counterpart does have a closed form in terms of the special [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):

$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(\sin x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(\cos x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2J_0(1).$$

Also, $$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(\sin x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(\cos x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2H_0(1),$$

where *H* represents the special [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28cos%28sinx%29%29) but no standard integral found.
So, you can approximate the function to an easier function.

cos(sin(x)) = a cos(bx)+c

if a = 0.25, b = 2, c = 0.75

then the approximation is almost inline with the function (I used a plotting program for this conclusion).

$$
\int f(x)dx = \int 0.25\cos(2x)+0.75\ dx \\= 0.5\sin(2x)\ +0.75x+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

Or you also can solve it numerically by expand the function (e.g. use [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)) 
and then integrate each of its terms (e.g. first 5 terms).

Answer (score 0):

You can express in terms of [Incomplete Bessel Functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf):

Consider $$\begin{align}J_0(1,w)&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^w\cos\cos x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\cos\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)~d\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\sin x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^0\cos\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)~d\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_\pi^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos(\pi-x)~d(\pi-x)
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\cos x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi\cos\cos x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos\cos x~dx
\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx-J_0(1)\end{align}
$$

Then $\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{w+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\sin x~dx=J_0(1)+J_0(1,w)$

$\therefore\int\cos\sin x~dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(J_0(1)+J_0\left(1,x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)+C$